# Is it possible to make the openshift core dns reachable to other vms outside the openshift platform?

Tags: kubernetes, dns, openshift, coredns

I am creating external services names to pods and make them outside reachable through CNames. I want also that vms outside the k8 cluster will be able to use as a preferred DNS server the core dns ?

Is this possible ?